# glyphicon won't display on c9

Tags: ruby, glyphicons

I'm currently using c9 to develop a web service w/ ruby on rails. I've installed bootstrap AND bootstrap-glyphicon gems.

The problem is that with the same line of code, some of the glyphicons will display, but some won't.
The only difference between the two is the glyphicon class name.

Is this to do with bootstrap gem(should I try with CDN?) or is it because of the directory?

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Could you please post some relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to link to the glyphicon files in the css like so

```
@import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css");
```

**or in the HTML**

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
```